# "Atomic rendering" in Swing

Tags: java, swing, canvas, rendering

I have a swing application that contains an SVG canvas inside a JScrollPane.
The application modifies the displayed SVG document, which also leads to a change of the size of the document.
This size change needs to be reflected in the application. The SVG canvas is resized and the viewport of the JScrollPane is scrolled so that it displays the correct section of the canvas.

However, this leads to something like a "visual jumping", because the user first sees the change of the canvas size and after that sees the scrolling operation.

Is there a way to tell java to stop processing rendering events on a given component (and its subcomponents) and only resume after I have finished my modifications to only display the result of all modifications?

Here is my idea in pseudo code:

```
myScrollPane.suspendRendering();
svgDocument.changeSize();
svgCanvas.changeSize();
myScrollPane.getViewport().scrollToCorrectPosition;
myScrollPane.resumeRendering();
```

I tried with `myScrollPane.setIgnoreRepaint(true)`, but it seems to not have any effect here (even if I never set `ignoreRepaint` to `false` again.

And here is an SSCCE that tries to simulate the effect:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Jumping extends JFrame {
  private JButton innerPanel= new JButton("Some silly, useless text, just for fun. And it goes on even longer. But that's not a problem.");
  private JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
  private JButton btnJump= new JButton("Jump");

  private int lastWidth= 1024;

  public Jumping(){
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(btnJump, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    this.scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    this.innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
    this.innerPanel.setSize(1024, 768);
    this.innerPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
    this.innerPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
    this.setSize(640, 480);

    this.btnJump.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
          System.err.println("> actionPerfomed");
          //resize the canvas
          new Thread(){
            public void run() {
              System.err.println("> SwingWorker.doInBackground "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

              SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                  System.err.println("> resize canvas "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                  final int newWidth= (int) (lastWidth * 1.5);
                  innerPanel.setSize(newWidth, 768);
                  innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(newWidth, 768));
                  innerPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(newWidth, 768));
                  innerPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(newWidth, 768));
                  lastWidth= newWidth;
                  System.err.println("< resize canvas "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                }
              });

              //scroll to correct position
              SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                  System.err.println("> scroll to pos "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

                  try {
                    System.err.println("< sleep "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.err.println("> sleep "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  final Point viewPos= scrollPane.getViewport().getViewPosition();
                  scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(viewPos.x + 50, viewPos.y));
                  System.err.println("< scroll to pos "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                }
              });

              System.err.println("< SwingWorker.doInBackground "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
            }
          }.start();
          System.err.println("< actionPerfomed "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        }catch(Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    final Jumping frame= new Jumping();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Beware that all changes to the UI should be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thats not so easy. I tried, but with a really simple SSCCE it doesn't happen (or at least isn't visible). I use Batik as SVG toolkit, and since it only works highly asynchronously, it adds a lot of complexity in it self. Actually the size change of the svgDocument and the svgCanvas therefore happen in a different thread than the scrolling to the new position.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am aware of that, but that is also not the problem (maybe it is, but can't be avoided of the asynchronous nature of the Batik toolkit).

Comment: *"Thats not so easy."* I never said it would be easy, but then, that's why they pay us the 'big bucks'.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added an SSCCE. Of course it is not the same as in my real application, but you can at least see the jumping, since I delay the scrolling operation a bit.

Comment: @radlan The problem is that you don't execute your changes to the UI in the EDT. The changes to the UI **must** be done on the EDT. If you want the changes to look "Atomic" make sure that it all happens within a single event (`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { performAllChangesToTheUI()}});`), both the size modification and scrolling.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet That's the problem. I can't. Batik is very asynchronous. I need to change the canvas size, then wait until batik informs me about the finished SVG rendering. Then I can calculate the new position to scroll to. I tried to simulate that effect in my example above.

Comment: @radlan Could you post a very simple example (with SVG/Batik) code so that we can see how we can sort this out? My guess is that you should modify the size of the Batik elements, then wen Batik is done, update the size/preferredsize of the batik component, scroll to the correctr position

Answer (score 1):

Generally one possibility is using a custom RepaintManager. A simplistic, and very much unoptimized example follows:

```
public class FreezableRepaintManager extends RepaintManager {
    final Set<Component> frozen = new HashSet<Component>();

    public void freeze(Container c) {
        frozen.add(c);
        for (Component child : c.getComponents()) {
            if (child instanceof Container) {
                freeze((Container) child);
            } else {
                frozen.add(child);
            }
        }
    }

    public void thaw(final Container c) {
        frozen.remove(c);
        for (Component child : c.getComponents()) {
            if (child instanceof Container) {
                thaw((Container) child);
            } else {
                frozen.remove(child);
            }
        }
        c.repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        if (!frozen.contains(c)) {
            super.addDirtyRegion(c, x, y, w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

Set the repaint manager somewhere early in your code with `RepaintManager.setCurrentManager()` and then use `freeze(componentTree)` before staring the series of operations and follow with `thaw(componentTree)` once you're done.

That works for most components, but unfortunately JScrollPane is one for which it is not enough, as it does more complicated drawing than most. So you may need a JScrollPane whose createViewport() returns a view port that can suppress the blits, such as:

```
class FreezableViewport extends JViewport {
    private boolean frozen;

    public void freeze() {
        frozen = true;
    }

    public void thaw() {
        frozen = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeBlit(int dx, int dy, Point blitFrom,
        Point blitTo, Dimension blitSize, Rectangle blitPaint) {
        if (frozen) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.computeBlit(dx, dy, blitFrom, blitTo, blitSize, blitPaint);
    }
}
```

That would need also freezing before the series of modifications, and with the above repaint manager, thawing *before* the thaw method of the repaint manager is called.